# Angular Uncaught Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular so i'm still getting my head around how it works. I've stumbled into a problem however (quite early on...) and the below code is giving me "Uncaught Object" in the console and breaks Angular. The .config section is the culprit, if I remove it, the page loads fine. I'm not entirely sure how the error is being caused because to me, everything looks fine?

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl: '/app/views/admin.html',
                controller: 'DashboardController'
            })
            .otherwise('/', {
                redirectTo: '/'
            })

        $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
    }])

    .controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', function ($scope, Security) {
        $scope.security = Security;
    }])
```

Comment: What is the `Security` object that you're injecting?

Comment: What does your HTMl look like? Are you including Angular's routeProvider js file?

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis yeah the file ref is included and I've preprended the route script with an alert() to ensure it's being fetched.

Comment: Btw, the frustratingly vague "Uncaught Object" error in Chrome doesn't really help. But if you open the page in Canary, the error will be more verbose. (i.e. "Uncaught object: no module named app.account Line 12312")

Answer (score 30):

I had the same error; if you activate Chrome to pause on exceptions, you'll be able to have more detailed error information
[image: angular uncaught object]

Comment: This was life saver. I never used pause on exceptions but always setting break points.

Comment: +1 for "pause on exceptions" and helpful screen image.

Answer (score 6):

`.otherwise` takes only one parameter - an object which contains information on what needs to be done for routes that are not defined.

In your case, you seem to be passing a route to it in addition to an object.

Replace:

```
.otherwise('/', {
    redirectTo: '/'
})
```

with

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/dashboard'
});
```

Note that you need to redirect to a path that exists. '/' is a path that does not exist. '/dashboard' is a path that does, hence you redirect to it. Or, define a handler for '/' path

Comment: It seems to be more of a module dependency error. Two things - have you declared your `ng-app` properly? Have you included the `angular-route.js` file?

Comment: ng-app is declared like so: <html ng-app="app"> and here's a console log showing the inclusion of angular-route http://cl.ly/image/2L0X2u0T2l2R

Comment: Can you check if you have any additional spaces in your code? Especially if a new line begins

Comment: There are no additional spaces

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting my *own* solution, as several factors seem to be behind this issue and nobody has talked about this so far.

That is, try to write your code outside of `$.ready()`;

```
<script>
$(function(){
  // This leaves "Uncaught object" error in Chrome!
  // var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);
});

// So get it out of $.ready()!! 
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this instance it looks like the error has been caused by this:

```
$locationProvider.html5mode(true); <-- mode should be capital 'M'.
```

Comment: Thanks, my typo was: `$locationProvider.html5Moode(true);` I was looking for hours ...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your angular.js is loaded before angular-route.js in your HTML file.
like:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, in my case it was due to using UI-Router and having a duplicated state name.